# apabackref error because of keyval (after updating to biber 2.14 and biblatex 3.14)

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style, key-value

It seems that `apabackref` is in conflict with `biblatex` (version 3.14). I updated from 3.7 or so, where I had no problems. Probably the error is due to `biber` (version 2.14; if formerly used 2.7, I suspect). I am not able to explore this due to my non-existing knowledge/abilities.

Here is the MWE, if one leaves out `apabackref=true` there is no error message.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, apabackref=true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\textcite{key}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The error message is this:

> ```
> ! Package keyval Error: apabackref undefined.
>
>  See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
>  Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
>  l.15107 \blx@processoptions
> ```

Is it my fault or is this really a problem with `apabackref`? Are there any (neat) solutions?

Comment: Try `backref=true` instead. (perhaps it is actually the default, don't know). In any case apabackref has been removed: https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/72

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. I was not aware of this issue 72. However, I could have tried ```backref=true``` on my on …

Comment: Could you turn this into an answer? Or how should we proceed? Obviously, the problem is not due to versions of bibtex or biber -- so probably I should change the question as well?!

Comment: Please do not add the answer in the question. There is no need to add an update when the question is answered. Accepting an answer already shows that for you the issue is resolved.

Comment: I rolled back the edit adding the answer on top of the question. Hope you are OK with that.

Comment: Yes, thank you, @moewe. I am still learning the rules of stackexchange, and am actually thankful for your correction (incl. the editing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `backref=true`. The `apabackref` option has been remove some time ago from biblatex-apa. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/72.

Comment: Again beaten by a few seconds! This is getting out of hand. (Though I only just realised you were more than an hour quicker in the comments.)

Comment: @moewe sorry ;-)

Comment: I am hard pressed and do not know whose answer I should accept. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The `apabackref` option was removed from `biblatex-apa` in version 9.1 (2019-11-27) and v8.2 (2019-12-01) of `biblatex-apa6` because the coexistence of the standard `backref` option and a style-specific `apabackref` option was just confusing. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/72 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/84.

Just use the normal `backref` option that is compatible with the standard styles instead.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, backref=true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E., & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4h377::AID-JCC1i3.0.CO;2-P (cit. on p. 1)]

---

### Note for people who update from an older version of `biblatex-apa`

Since version 9.0 (2019-11-23) `biblatex-apa` has implemented APA style from the 7th edition of the manual. Older versions implemented 6th-edition APA style.

If you need 6th-edition APA style use `biblatex-apa6` (`style=apa6`).